# Selection Sorting in C++ not working correctly

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

I was doing selection sort, it is running completely but the results are not correct.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
  int array[5], temp, min, i, j; 
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
  { 
    cout << "Enter the value"<<endl; 
    cin >> array[i]; 
  } 
  cout << "Values before sorting:" << endl; 
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
    cout << array[i] << " "; 

  cout << endl; 
  for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
  { 
    min = i; 
    for(j = i + 1; j <= 4; j++) 
    { 
      if(array[j] < array[min]) 
        min = j; 

      if(min != i) 
      { 
        temp = array[j]; 
        array[j] = array[j + 1]; 
        array[j + 1] = temp; 
      } 
    } 
    cout << "values after sorting" << endl; 
    for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
      cout << array[i] << " ";  
  } 
}
```

can anyone tell me whats the error in my code

Comment: You should copy paste that code here instead of creating an image.

Comment: try many but unable to post that ,so posted the image =D

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int array[5],temp,min,i,j;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl;
  cin>>array[i];
 }
 cout<<"values before sorting"<<endl;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  cout<<array[i]<<" ";
 }
 cout<<endl;
 for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
  min=i;
  for(j=i+1;j<=4;j++)
  {
   if(array[j] < array[min] )
   {
    min=j;
    
   }
   if(min != i)
   {
    temp=array[j];
    array[j]=array[j+1];
    array[j+1]=temp;
   }
  }
  cout<<"values after sorting"<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
  {
   cout<<array[i]<<" ";
  }
 }
}

Comment: By here, I mean edit your question. And what if that link expires? This thread will be useless.

Comment: When you index by adding to or subtracting from the loop variable inside a loop, you need to be careful so you're not overstepping your boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the way you update the array after finding the minimum.
In each iteration, you should find the minimum value between array[i]..array[4], and then you need to swap array[i] with array[min] as follows:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    int array[5],temp,min,i,j; 
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++) 
    { 
        cout<<"Enter the value"<<endl; 
        cin>>array[i]; 
    } 
    cout<<"values before sorting"<<endl; 
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++) 
    { 
        cout<<array[i]<<" "; 
    } 
    cout<<endl; 
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i)
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = temp;
        }
    }
    cout << "values after sorting" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the correction

Comment: why we use second swapping in 1st loop ?

Comment: for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] < array[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i)
        {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = temp;
        }
    }

Comment: What do you mean by "second swapping"? There is only one swap: After we find the "min" at each iteration of the first loop, we do the swap. This brings the min value to place #i in the list.